# Google ActivityRecognitionApi not firing any callbacks

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

GooglePlayServices recently changed from the way you detect the users activity - from using ActivityRecognitionClient to ActivityRecognitionApi. I have followed all the examples I can find but must have missed something.

After making the call to GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext).addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)...build() I was expecting that one of the connection callback methods would be called. I have logging and breakpoints in all the callback methods but none of them are ever called.

OnReceive() and CallClient() are called as expected and the manifest file includes: uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"

What am I missing? I would love to get to the bottom of this given the amount of time I have wasted so far.

(P.S. It's my own Logging library - it is not part of the issue)

```
public class BootAtStartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{



private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
private PendingIntent mpIntent;
private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.d,TAG,"inside onReceive: " + intent.getAction());
    if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) || (intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastIntentConstants.ACTIVITY_FIRST_TIME_CALL_SERVICE)))
    {
        mContext = context;
        callClient();
    }
}


private void callClient() {

    Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.d,TAG,"inside callClient");

    int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
    if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    } else {
        Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.e, getClass().getName(), "Google play Services are not available.");
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.d,TAG,"inside onConnected");

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class);
    mpIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 1000, mpIntent);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.d,TAG,"inside onDisconnected");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.d,TAG,"inside onConnectionSuspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Logging.log(Logging.enumLoggingLevel.d,TAG,"inside onConnectionFailed");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing the call to connect() after the build? The callbacks dont fire unless you call connect.

```
mGoogleApiClient.connect()
```

Comment: That's exactly what it was...can't believe that I missed it. Thanks for the solution.